# Android Studio - Interstitial ads load issue

Tags: java, android, admob

So I am trying to add Interstitial ads to my project.

This is my what my code looks like for the current `JHAActivity.java`:

Note: In my project I am using my own Ad unit ID from apps.admob.com insted of `ca-app-pub-1111111111111111/2222222222`.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class JHAActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button jhaButton;

    // private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; Test AD
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1111111111111111/2222222222";

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // R.menu.mymenu is a reference to an xml file named mymenu.xml which should be inside your res/menu directory.
        // If you don't have res/menu, just create a directory named "menu" inside res
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // handle button activities
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.mybutton) {
            // do something here

            if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")) { // If English
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.rules)
                        .setMessage(rulesENG)

                        // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            } else { // Else if not English
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.rules)
                        .setMessage(rules)

                        // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jha);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }
        });

        jhaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        jhaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openJHA();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    private void openJHA() {

        counter++;

        if (counter == 5) {
            showInterstitial(); // Display AdMob AD
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically when using `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712` as Ad unit ID, it displays the test ad each time I have pressed the `jhaButton` 5 times, but when using my own Ad unit ID, the ad does not show up at all. In the run log it just says: `D/TAG: The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }
```

your `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(xxx)` tried to load once but it is often that `onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError)` returned and if you didn't do sth like `mInterstitialAd.loadAd` again to get a try, it will stop and never jump to `onAdLoaded()`. Hence your `mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()` will almost return false.

Every time you want to use `mInterstitialAd.showAd()`, please check first `if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){mInterstitialAd.showAd() }` first

The big problem is that recent Admob used SDK v19.7.0 . codes related to InterestitialAd need to be modified again...And I don't know why the callback lose the function about `onAdClicked`.